# Scraping with Python Selenium: iterate through html table without tags

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm a Python neophyte working on a fun little scraping project.  Trying to pull info from here:
http://www.airfleets.net/flottecie/American%20Airlines.htm

I'm in Python 2 and using Selenium

There's a table on the page with aircraft details.  I want to iterate through the second column of this table, which is labeled "Active".  Normally, I would select the table by using `find_element_by_id`.  However, this table doesn't have an `id` tag.  I think I need to find the table by `find_element_by_xpath`, but I am unsure of the path syntax to find the table and then also the rows in the second column.

In summary, how can I iterate through the rows of a table if the table does not have any identifying tags?

Comment: you can get elements by_tag or by_class. It gives list of elements and you can work like with normal list - using index (`lst[x]`), `for` loop (`for x in lst`), etc. you can event use `find_element_by` with every element on list to get "subelement". BTW. Chrome and Firefox has DevTools and you can see "xpath" or "css selector" (sometimes you need install extension)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use CSS selector or XPath. As mentioned in the comments, your browser's dev tools probably have a builtin way to do this.

That table's Xpath is

```
/html/body/table[4]/tbody/tr[1]/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table
```

And a CSS selector that you can use is

```
body > table:nth-child(6) > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td > table:nth-child(3) > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) > table
```

In Chrome, for example, you can obtain this information in the following way:

(1) Open up the dev tools and find the element. You can do this by right-clicking any element and clicking "inspect"

[image]

2) Right-click the element in the DOM, then select Copy > (Copy Selector / Copy XPath[image]